# Issue with NULL byte at URL

Tags: php, apache, url

Suppose we have the following PHP scripts

```
if(isset($_GET['adr'])) {
    $adr = $_GET['adr'];
    include $adr.".txt";
}
```

I want to load a non text file, For this purpose I use `mysite.com/?adr=g:/file.asd%00` URL, in the other side we all know all strings in PHP must terminated by NULL byte (i.e. %00). But when I request this URL the Apache server tells me:

> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'g:/file.asd' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in G:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\index.php on line 16

Can anyone please tell me why this does not work?
Thanks

Comment: Strings in PHP are null-terminated? Since when?

Comment: "we all know all strings in PHP must terminated by NULL byte". No they're not. Get rid of the `%00`.

Comment: Problem is unclear (what *should* this do? why do you expect it to do so? what file exactly are you trying to include?) and probably based on a nonsensical premise. Voting to close.

Comment: @deceze I want to include `g:/file.asd` but in server side codes append a `.txt` to the requested file but I want to bypass this, and include a `asd` file

Comment: So you're trying to find an exploit for the posted code based on a NUL-byte injection; and you're wondering why it doesn't work? Does `include 'g:/file.asd';` work, for starters?

Comment: @ABFORCE You cannot do this. [This bug was fixed in PHP 5.3](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39863). (I think that's relevant but maybe not I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside the massive security implications of `include`ing a file based on user input without validation, here's what I'd do:

```
if( strpos($adr,".") === false) $adr .= ".txt";
```

Basically, this appends `.txt` *only* if there is not already a file extension (or at least, something that looks like it might be a file extension)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about using NULL byte in urls.

When creating URL and passing parameter you should use urlencode function as below:

```
$x = 'ysite.com/?adr='.urlencode('g:/file.asd');
```

and you should make sure that file `g:/file.asd.txt` exists

Extra question - are you sure you have your file saved? In warning there is `Failed opening 'g:/file.asd' for inclusion` and in your code you include `g:/file.asd.txt` file.

Of course you can do this only on your localhost. IF you do it on live server, simple don't because anyone can quick reveal all filesystem data and do anything they want.

Comment: Erm, no... that's already done by the server before even starting PHP.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol My mistake,  already changed that

Comment: Again, won't make any difference. While `:` and `/` *do* have meaning in URLs in general, they don't have that meaning in the query string and therefore don't require escaping.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol But if using this way other strange characters may also appear in Url and those might need urlencoding